# Path change using recursion testdome

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a problem with using recursion inside classes, I don't usually use POO in python, and I made some code that appear to work, but at the end does not return the value, but if I print the values inside the conditions, appear to do what I need.

The problem is one of the public problems of testdome; implement a code that allow you to change directory without using library functions, and I think the best way is using recursion.

```py
class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.current_path = path

    def cd(self, new_path):
        tokenizado_cd = new_path.split("/")
        tokenizado_cp = self.current_path.split("/")# solo obtener los nombres de carpetas
        nueva_ruta = ""

        if new_path=="":
            return self

        if tokenizado_cd[0] =="":
            ## se cambiara a un path desde root (absoluto)
            self = Path("/")
            if(len(tokenizado_cd)==2 and tokenizado_cd[0]=="" and tokenizado_cd[1]==""):
                return self
            return self.cd("/".join(tokenizado_cd[1:]))

        elif tokenizado_cd[0] =="..":
            ## Se mueve un path atras
            self = Path("/".join(tokenizado_cp[:-1]))
            print(self.current_path)
            if(len(tokenizado_cd)==1):
                return self
            return self.cd("/".join(tokenizado_cd[1:]))


        elif tokenizado_cd[0].isalpha() and len(tokenizado_cd[0])==1:
            ## Se cambia a un path relativo
            print("alpha")
            self = Path("/".join(tokenizado_cp)+"/"+str(tokenizado_cd[0]))
            if(len(tokenizado_cd)==1):
                print(self.current_path)
                return self
            return self.cd("/".join(tokenizado_cd[1:]))


path = Path('/a/b/c/d')
path.cd('../../x/k')
print(path.current_path)
```

The expected result is "/a/b/x/k " what is printed before the last line, and what I'm getting is "/a/b/c/d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have designed your class to be immutable, i.e. you return a *new* instance when you need a different path. By consequence, you should take the returned, new instance whenever you call the `cd` method:

```
path = path.cd('../../x/k')
```